# Doubt regarding adjoining elements to ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Using the Proposition  11.5.5 in Michael Artin Algebra  book, 
$ \frac{\mathbb Z_2[x]}{x^2+1}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2[i]$ where i satisfies the equation  $x^2+1$.
Now $ x^2+1 =(x-1)^2$ .  That is i=1.  Then $\mathbb Z_2[i]=\mathbb Z_2$. But in that case $ \frac{\mathbb Z_2[x]}{x^2+1}$ will be field, which is not true. 
Secondly, by the same proposition $ \frac{\mathbb R[x]}{x^2-4}$ will be isomorphic  to $\mathbb R[2]$ as 2 is the root of $x^2-4$. Then $\mathbb R[2]$ is isomorphic  to $\mathbb R$.  But by Chinese Remainder Theorem $ \frac{\mathbb R[x]}{x^2-4}$  is isomorphic  to $\mathbb R$ X $ \mathbb R$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The original thing seems wrong to me because $x^2+1$ is not irreducible in that field, it has the double root of 1.   If you want the irreducible quadratic, you need $x^2+x+1$

Comment: But in the book irreducibility of polynomial is not mentioned. The statement  given in the book is " If R is a ring and f is any monic polynomial of positive degree,  then R[a] is isomorphic to R[x]/(f), where f(a)=0.

Comment: @simutiyam In my copy of Artin it says "Let $R[\alpha]$ denote the ring $R[x]/(f)$ obtained by adjoining an element satisfying the relation $f(\alpha)=0$." This is a definition, not a statement of an isomorphism. Thus, "$\mathbb Z_2[i]$ where $i^2=-1$" does *by definition* refer to the ring $\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $i$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$ in this quotient.

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, in $Z_2[x]$, the polynomial $x^2+1$ factors as
$$
x^2+1=(x-1)^2
$$
hence. since $x^2+1$ is reducible in $Z_2[x]$, it follows that the ring $$R=Z_2[i]=Z_2[x]/(x^2+1)$$
is not an integral domain.

Thus, the identity
$$
(i-1)^2=0
$$
does not automatically imply$\;i-1=0$.

And as you noted, you can't have $i-1=0$, else $R$ would be isomorphic to $Z_2$.

The elements of the ring $R$ can be represented as
$$
0,\;1,\;i,\;i+1
$$
with addition respecting$\;2=0$, and multiplication respecting$\;2=0\;$and$\;i^2=1$.

Comment: x^2+1 is a polynomial over field Z_2. So x^2+1 will have at most two roots and x^2+1 =(x-1)^2. Now i has to satisfy x^2+1.  If i is not 1,  what is i then?   I am little confused

Comment: @simu tiyam: The symbol $i$ represents an element of $R$ whose defining relation is $i^2+1=0$. In particular, from that relation, you can't deduce $i=1$, so $i$ is not an element of $Z_2$.

Comment: @simu tiyam: Also note: The polynomial $x^2+1$ has at most two roots in any _field_ _extension_ of $Z_2$, but $R$ is not a field. In fact, the polynomial $x^2+1$ already has two roots in $Z_2$, namely $1,\,1$ (repeated roots).